# Inversion of &: in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby I'm selecting some hash values by key names this way

```
new_values = my_hash.values_at(:value2, :value3, :value6, :value8).select {|a| !a.empty?}
```

and what about this? It's not working.

```
new_values = my_hash.values_at(:value2, :value3, :value6, :value8).select(&:!empty?)
```

Comment: you cannot directly use symbol-to-proc for that, but you can implement the logically negated `Object#present?` method (like active_support does) which will probably useful somewhere else.

Comment: Why `Array`? Maybe those are strings?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: oh, ok, then Object#present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sergio explained there is no way to do this with standard Ruby since the expression you are using won't parse. One can hack something together so it works though (of course `reject` would be the way to go here):

```
['1', '', '11', ''].select(&fn(:empty?, :!))
#=> ["1", "11"]
```

Here's the implementation of `fn` as used in my [extension library](http://rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans):

```
def fn(*funs)
  -> x do
    funs.inject(x) do |v,f|
      Proc === f ? f.call(v) : v.send(f)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think, he wanted to do that to save a couple of characters. This approach does neither save space, nor is cleaner. But it's nice to have options :)

Comment: Sure, but he said he wanted alternatives. :-) I upvoted your answer cause it makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work, because there's no method with name `!empty?`. And this name is illegal in ruby, AFAIK. You either have to use full lambda form (as in your first snippet) or use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)

```
['1', '', '11', ''].select(&:empty?) # => ["", ""]
['1', '', '11', ''].reject(&:empty?) # => ["1", "11"]
```

Comment: No, I don't need to reject empty values. I need to make an inversion.

Comment: @Grienders: why don't you want to reject empty values? Result is the same.

Comment: I want to know an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about alternatives:

```
Not = 
  lambda do |x|
    p = x.to_proc 
    lambda do |*ys|
      !p[*ys]
    end
  end

['1', '', '11', ''].select(&Not[:empty?])
```

Can be easily extended to more interesting cases like compositions, fanouts.

Comment: Why is it named with "N" but "n"?

Comment: Because it's a constant in this particular case (I usually place it in a separate file and `require` it when I need it) and can be used everywhere.

Comment: then why isn't it named NOT?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse method for `empty?` is `any?`. With that you can achieve your goal by using

```
new_values = my_hash.values_at(:value2, :value3, :value6, :value8).select(&:any?)
```

Comment: As @Sergio said above, only if those are arrays, there may be strings.

Comment: `present?` is only available with ActiveSupport. So if this is actually important (and the OP doesn't use Rails), it is probably a good idea to just use the long block form.

Comment: I agree, the present? was just a side suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby):

```
class Symbol
  def on
    ->(*args) { yield(*args).send(self) }
  end
end

['1', '', '11', ''].select(&:!.on(&:empty?))
# => ["1", "11"]
```