# How can I map an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I have an array of integers

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I need to POW this numbers, so they can be like this

```
a 
# => [9, 16, 25, 36]
```

I'm trying to do this with this piece of code:

```
a.map!(&:**2)
```

but Isn't working :(

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you supply arguments to the map(&:method) syntax in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda with `&` if you so desire:

```
square = lambda { |x| x**2 }
a.map!(&square)
```

This sort of thing is pointless busywork with a block so simple but it can be nice if you have a chain of such things and the blocks are more complicated:

```
ary.select(&some_complicated_criteria)
   .map(&some_mangling_that_takes_more_than_one_line)
   ...
```

Collecting bits of logic in lambdas so that you can name the steps has its uses.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this

```
a.map! { |i| i**2 }
```

Read the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of rule, you cannot add parameters to methods using the `&:sym` syntax.

However, if you follow my suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711606/1120015) you could do the following:

```
class Symbol
  def with(*args, &block)
    ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &block) }
  end
end

a.map!(&:**.with(2))
# => [9, 16, 25, 36]
```

Comment: I think this is smart approach but shouldn't we be wary of modifying Symbol object for our use.

Comment: @amitamb we should if it changes in any way an _existing_ behavior (which might cause breakage in other parts of the code) - but adding a new method which keeps the object in question un-mutated is safe enough - it is actually quite ubiquitous - how do you think Rails got `1.day.ago`?

Comment: I know Rails add so many such features and agree that it is useful. But I have found that adding such support through initializers in Rails can make code bit unreadable. Or using this in a gem means we have to be sure gem user doesn't re-implement it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `&:` shortcut syntax if you are calling a method on the object with no arguments. In this case, you need to pass `2` as an argument to the `**` method.

Instead, expand the block to the full syntax

```
a.map! { |n| n**2 }
```

Comment: Can I do something like this? --> a.map(&2.method(:**))

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. `&` calls `to_proc` on the symbol (`:**`) given, and you can't express arguments in the symbol representing the method.

Comment: vhbsouze, see Arup's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23696043#23696043).

Comment: Alright, I'm learning now too, so this is for my benefit. Doesn't that answer rely on the commutativity of addition? I don't know if it will work here.

Comment: It won't work - but if you follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23711606/1120015 - you could do `a.map!(&:**.with(2))`