# Merge duplicates in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes in ruby:

```
[
  {name: 'one', tags: 'xxx'},
  {name: 'two', tags: 'yyy'},
  {name: 'one', tags: 'zzz'},
]
```

and i'm looking for any clean ruby solution, which will make it able to simply merge all the duplicates in that array (by merging i mean concatinating the `tags` param) so the above example will be transformed to:

```
[
  {name: 'one', tags: 'xxx, zzz'},
  {name: 'two', tags: 'yyy'},
]
```

I can iterate through each array element, check if there is a duplicate, merge it with the original entry and delete the duplicate but i feel that there can be a better solution for this and that there are some caveats in such approach i don't know about. Thanks for any clue.

Comment: You might find [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of as

```
arr = [
  {name: 'one', tags: 'xxx'},
  {name: 'two', tags: 'yyy'},
  {name: 'one', tags: 'zzz'},
]

merged_array_hash = arr.group_by { |h1| h1[:name] }.map do |k,v|
  { :name => k, :tags =>  v.map { |h2| h2[:tags] }.join(" ,") } 
end

merged_array_hash
# => [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"xxx ,zzz"}, {:name=>"two", :tags=>"yyy"}]
```

Comment: @Ven No.. To make it work, you need to create some proc object, then you can use it...

Comment: @Ven look into the highly voted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23711606#23711606) to understand what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that makes use of the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash.merge!`) that takes a block for determining the merged value for every key that is present in both of the two hashes being merged.

**Code**

```
def combine(a)
  a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update({ g[:name]=>g }) { |k,hv,gv|
           { name: k, tags: hv[:tags]+", "+gv[:tags] } } }.values  
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [{name: 'one', tags: 'uuu'},
     {name: 'two', tags: 'vvv'},
     {name: 'one', tags: 'www'},
     {name: 'six', tags: 'xxx'},
     {name: 'one', tags: 'yyy'},
     {name: 'two', tags: 'zzz'}]

combine(a)
  #=> [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu, www, yyy"},
  #    {:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv, zzz"     },
  #    {:name=>"six", :tags=>"xxx"          }]
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
a = [{name: 'one', tags: 'uuu'},
     {name: 'two', tags: 'vvv'},
     {name: 'one', tags: 'www'}]

b = a.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"},
  #                  {:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"},
  #                  {:name=>"one", :tags=>"www"}]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert the enumerator `b` to an array to see what values it will pass into its block:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [[{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}, {}],
  #    [{:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"}, {}],
  #    [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"www"}, {}]]
```

The first value passed to the block and assigned to the block variables is:

```
g,h = [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}, {}]
g #=> {:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}
h #=> {}
```

The first merge operation is now performed (the merged `h` is returned):

```
h.update({ g[:name] => g })
  #=> h.update({ "one" => {:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"} })
  #=> {"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}}
```

`h` does not have the key `"one"`, so `update`'s block is not involed.

Next, the enumerator `b` passes the following into the block:

```
g #=> {:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"}
h #=> {"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}}
```

so we execute:

```
h.update({ g[:name] => g })
  #=> h.update({ "two"=>{:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"})
  #=> {"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"},
  #    "two"=>{:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"}}
```

Again, `h` does not have the key `"two"`, so the block is not used.

Lastly, `each_with_object` passes the final tuple into the block:

```
g #=> {:name=>"one", :tags=>"www"}
h #=> {"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"},
  #    "two"=>{:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"}}
```

and we execute:

```
h.update({ g[:name] => g })
  #=> h.update({ "one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"www"})
```

`h` has a key/value pair with key `"one"`:

```
"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"}
```

`update`'s block is therefore executed to determine the merged value. The following values are passed to that block's variables:

```
k #=> "one"
hv #=> {:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu"} <h's value for "one">
gv #=> {:name=>"one", :tags=>"www"} <g's value for "one">
```

and the block calculation creates this hash (as the merged value for the key "one"):

```
{ name: k, tags: hv[:tags]+", "+gv[:tags] }
  #=> { name: "one", tags: "uuu" + ", " + "www" }
  #=> { name: "one", tags: "uuu, www" }
```

So the merged hash now becomes:

```
h #=> {"one"=>{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu, www"},
  #    "two"=>{:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"     }}
```

All that remains is to extract the values:

```
h.values  
  #=> [{:name=>"one", :tags=>"uuu, www"}, {:name=>"two", :tags=>"vvv"}]
```