# What is `&method` called? How to pass multiple arguments in it?

Tags: ruby, proc

What I know:

I can call a method with object as parameter in ruby like this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(&method(:Integer))
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

`&method` (basically `&`) tells its a proc and not an object. Based on it I can define and call my own method too. Like:

```
def res_str(val)
  puts val
end

["1", "2", "3"].each(&method(:res_str))
# 1
# 2
# 3
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Now what if my method takes more than one argument?

```
def res_str(val, str)
  puts "#{val} - #{str}"
end
```

My Questions:

- How can I pass more than one argument in the method using this technique?
- What is this technique called?

PS: I tried to frame my questions as per my understanding. If I am fundamentally wrong at it, please care to explain.

Comment: "its a proc and not an object" -- This is contradictory. A proc is an object.

Comment: Have a look at @Uri's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23711606#23711606).

Comment: @CarySwoveland that completely answers my 1st question. Thanks

Comment: @sawa I was still trying to understand your answer. I didnot commented yet, as I was going through some basic concepts to understand it better so I can ask question (or accept) accordingly. I didnot hated it by any mean