# Map multidimensional array with join as proc

Tags: ruby, proc

can I pass argument, to symbol passed to map method ?

Code:

`[["a", "airway", "sarsaparilas"], ["a", "sarsaparilas", "airway"]].map!(&:join)`

Results in:

`["aairwaysarsaparilas", "asarsaparilasairway"]`

Result I'm interested in:

`["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]`

I know how to use those methods separately, but this time I'm interested in symbol solution :)

Comment: See @UriAgassi's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23711606#23711606).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing it that way, but if you insist, this is a way to do it:

```
$, = " "
[["a", "airway", "sarsaparilas"], ["a", "sarsaparilas", "airway"]].map!(&:join)
#=> ["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]
```

If necessary, you can revert `$,` back to the default value after doing this.

```
$, = nil
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, could you explain why you would not recommend using this approach ?

Comment: It is because using `Symbol#to_proc` with `&` is a shorthand for a simple method without arguments. Insisting to use it with arguments is not making it any shorter or more readable. For this particular case, you can do it as I wrote above, but I don't see that writing `$, = " "` is any simpler than writing the join block with the argument

Answer (score 3):

You can define `Array::to_proc` to use an array instead a symbol:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    ->(element) { element.send(*self) }
  end
end
```

And now you can use like this:

```
a=[["a", "airway", "sarsaparilas"], ["a", "sarsaparilas", "airway"]]
a.map &[:join] # => ["aairwaysarsaparilas", "asarsaparilasairway"] 
a.map &[:join, ' '] # => ["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]
```

Answer (score 2):

> can I pass argument, to symbol

Someone created a gem for that:

```
require 'ampex'

arr = [["a", "airway", "sarsaparilas"], ["a", "sarsaparilas", "airway"]]

p arr.map!(&X.join(' '))

--output:--
["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]
```

You have to write `&X.` instead of `:`

Comment: This is very interesting tool, thx :) Just for reference, here's the [link](https://github.com/rapportive-oss/ampex) for this library.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is creating a method that does that.

```
def my_join(a)
  a.join(" ")
end

arr = [["a", "airway", "sarsaparilas"], ["a", "sarsaparilas", "airway"]]

arr.map &method(:my_join) # => ["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]
```

Of course this does not seem much better then using a proc

```
my_join = proc {|a| a.join(" ") }

arr.map &my_join # => ["a airway sarsaparilas", "a sarsaparilas airway"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass a block in, instead of writing `&:join`:

```
a = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
a.map { |x| x.join(' ') }  # => ["a b c", "d e f"]
```

The `&:join` syntax is just a shortcut for making a block that calls `.join` on its argument, but that syntax is not appropriate in every situation.