# Ruby on Rails 4 - Use model method to sort with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to sort my results by a method in that model but the model method needs some arguments, that's where I have problems.
My model is called Event and I'm trying to use

```
Event.all.sort_by(&:user_score("2", "51.4980749", "10.8119977"))
```

The method user score needs some arguments

```
def user_score user_id, latitude, longitude  
  return 0 
end
```

The return 0 of course is just to test it but it already fails when I call the function:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):12: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
...Event.all.sort_by(&:user_score("2", "51.4980749", ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure, the problem is with calling method using `block` notation. i.e `&:user_score("2", "51.4980749", "10.8119977")`

Can you please try the same in more explicit way as follows,

```
Event.all.sort_by{|e| e.user_score("2", "51.4980749", "10.8119977")}
```

OR

Please find this post [Can you supply arguments to the map(&:method) syntax in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23695653/5076451)