# Mapping enumerators

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Using an `Enumerator` in Ruby is pretty straightforward:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
enumerator = a.map
enumerator.each(&:succ) # => [2, 3, 4]
```

But can I do something similar with nested collections?

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
a.map(&:map) # => [#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>, #<Enumerator: [4, 5, 6]:map>]
```

But now how do I get `[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]`?

This could always be done with a block:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
a.map { |array| array.map(&:succ) } # => [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

But I was wondering if there was a way that avoided the use of a block, partly because I find it annoying to have to type `|array| array` and also partly because I'm curious to find a way to do it.

Ideally, it would feel like this psuedocode:

```
a.map.map(&:succ)
# perhaps also something like this
a.map(&:map).apply(&:succ)
```

Comment: See my update a previous SO Post suggested that something similar to your request can be supported (Although I still would not recommend it but for the sake of completeness it seemed worth mentioning)

Comment: You could do this: `p = ->(e) { e.map(&:succ) }; a.map(&p) #=> [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know of doing this is to do the following:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
a.map { |b| b.map(&:succ) } # => [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Mainly because of the combination of [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-map)/[`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc), you cannot pass a second variable to the block that `#map` yields for, and thus pass another variable to the inner `#map`:

```
a.map(1) { |b, c| c } # c => 1, but this doesn't work :(
```

So you *have* to use the block syntax; `Symbol#to_proc` actually returns a proc that takes any number of arguments (you can test this by doing `:succ.to_proc.arity`, which returns `-1`).  The first argument is used as the receiver, and the next few arguments are used as arguments to the method - this is demonstrated in `[1, 2, 3].inject(&:+)`.  However,

```
:map.to_proc.call([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], &:size) #=> [3, 3]
```

How?  `:map.to_proc` creates this:

```
:map.to_proc # => proc { |receiver, *args, &block| receiver.send(:map, *args, &block) }
```

This is then called with the array of arrays as an argument, with this block:

```
:size.to_proc # => proc { |receiver, *args, &block| receiver.send(:size, *args, &block) }
```

This results in `.map { |receiver| receiver.size }` being effectively called.

This all leads to this - since `#map` doesn't take extra arguments, and passes them to the block as parameters, you have to use a block.

Comment: Excellent explanation as to why this is not a possible syntax.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge there is no specific implementation as per the way you requested it.

You could just create a recursive function to handle this such as:

```
def map_succ(a)
  a.map {|arr| arr.is_a?(Array) ? map_succ(arr) : arr.succ}
end
```

Then it will work no matter how deeply nested the Array's are (caveat if the elements do not respond to `#succ` this will fail).

If you really wanted to you could monkey_patch Array **(IN NO WAY RECOMMENDED)**

```
#note if the element does not respond to `#succ` I have nullified it here
class Array 
  def map_succ
    map do |a| 
      if a.is_a?(Array) 
        a.map_succ 
      elsif a.respond_to?(:succ) 
        a.succ
      #uncomment the lines below to return the original object in the event it does not respond to `#succ`
      #else
        #a 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, [2, 3, 4]], {"test"=>"hash"}, "F"]
a.map_succ
#=> [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, [3, 4, 5]], nil, "G"]
```

The `nil` is because `Hash` does not have a `#succ` method.

**UPDATE**

Based on this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711606/1978251) a similar syntax could be supported but note that recursion is still probably your best bet here so that you can support any depth rather than an explicit one.

```
 #taken straight from @UriAgassi's from post above
 class Symbol
   def with(*args, &block)
     ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &block) }
   end
 end
```

Then

```
 a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
 a.map(&:map.with(&:succ))
 #=> [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
 a << [7,8,[9,10]] 
 #=> [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7],[7,8,[9,10]]]
 a.map(&:map.with(&:succ))
 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `succ' for [9, 10]:Array
```