# ArgumentError (0 for 1) when trying to use method as block like `&my_method`

Tags: ruby, proc

Let’s say I have this method `num_i_want?`, and I want to use it with `select` to filter my `nums` array.

```
def num_i_want?(num)
  num % 2 == 0
end

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I try to use the method as a block using the unary ampersand operator:

```
nums.select( &num_i_want? )
```

But I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from (irb):1:in `num_i_want?'
    from (irb):6
```

Why am I getting this error? And what is the simplest code I can use instead?

I know that `&:num_i_want?` doesn’t work. That tries to call `num_i_want?` on each number, which raises `NoMethodError` because `Integer#num_i_want?` doesn’t exist.

Of course, I could use `&:even?` to call [`Integer#even?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F), but let’s pretend the implementation of `num_i_want?` is more complicated than that.

Comment: See @UriAgassi's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23711606#23711606). (Not a dup.)

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
nums.select( &num_i_want? )
```

your code is actually being parsed like `& num_i_want?()`. First `num_i_want?` is called with no arguments, and *then* the ampersand operator is applied. Your problem is that you can’t refer to a method directly by name.

The simplest way to refer to a method is by passing a symbol to [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
nums.select( &method(:num_i_want?) )
#=> [2, 4]
```

If you are worried that using `Object#method` combined with `&` makes the code too clever and hard-to-read, the alternative is passing a normal block that just wraps `num_i_want?`:

```
nums.select { |num| num_i_want?(num) }
#=> [2, 4]
```