# Giving parameters to ampersand block

Tags: ruby, methods, proc

If we have a method on a collection that takes a block with another method executed on each element, we can write it shorter using ampersand. For example: if we have an array of integers and we want to remove the odd numbers we can do this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reject {|x| x.odd?}
```

Using ampersand, we can write this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].reject(&:odd?)
```

Let's say we have an array of strings, and we want to remove the elements containing `'a'`. We can write the solution like this:

```
['abc','cba','cbc','cdc','dca','cad','dc','cc].reject {|x| x.include? 'a'}
```

How do we write this using the ampersand syntax (if it's possible)?

Comment: This is not exactly possible although I have seen some pretty neat hacks to this concept.[Like this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23711606/1978251) What you are talking about is called `Symbol#to_proc` and googling pass arguments to `Symbol to_proc` will offer some insight but the out of the box answer is you don't.

Comment: [Great discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9076) about another similar chaining concept from ruby-lang.org. While I disagree with the premise of further polluting the ampersand (`&`) in ruby the conversation has some merit and makes for a though provoking read. My main concern with any of these concepts is the further you take a syntactical sugar the less readable the code becomes and one of my favorite parts about ruby is it's emphasis on human readable code.

Comment: Your "solution" is invalid.

Answer (score 8):

You can't, it is not possible.

`&` followed by a symbol is is a shortcut for a method that does not take any arguments.

As you said,

```
.reject(&:odd?)
```

Is a shortcut for:

```
 .reject {|x| x.odd?}
```

Basically, `&:SYMBOL` is always a shortcut for passing a block `{|x| x.SYMBOL}`

The reason this works is because calling the #to_proc method on a symbol returns a lambda expression that's a one-argument lambda, which calls the method with the same name as the symbol on it's argument.

And `&` converts from lambda to a block argument -- but beyond that, will call `to_proc` on it's operand before converting it to a block argument. So it calls `to_proc` on the symbol, and then gets a lambda from the symbol. And then passes this as a block argument to your method.

There's no way to use that shortcut when you need a block whose body goes beyond a one-argument block which just calls the method named after a symbol on it's argument.

Just write it out as you did. Nothing at all wrong with `.reject {|x| x.include? 'a'}`, just write that.