# Symbol#to_proc with parameters

Tags: ruby

Let's say you have a list in Ruby:

```
integer_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Selecting only the even numbers would be easy

```
integer_list.select(&:even?)
```

But what happens, if you had a mixed list?
And wanted to select only the integers
From what I've learned, I would write something like this:

```
mixed_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'string']
mixed_list.select { |x| x.is_a? Integer }
```

My question now is, is there a way to shorten this code like in the first example? Roughly like that:

```
mixed_list.select(&:is_a? Integer)
```

Comment: What if you have 

     def is_int?(x)
         x.is_a? Integer
     end;
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'string'].select(&method(:is_int?))

where defining a separate method to check if a given argument is an integer and call that method with the short hand mechanism.

Comment: @Uri Agassi's answer to the [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby) is a classic.