# Convert number array to string array

Tags: arrays, ruby

How from array with numbers:

```
a = [4,1,3]
```

make array:

```
s = ["****","*","***"]
```

So each number corresponds to amount of stars in a cell

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort on the OP's part to attempt to learn how to answer the question himself.  The question asks for a coding solution but does not clearly specify what language to use other than in the tags.  If this should be posted at all, it might be more appropriate at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Lack of effort is not a valid close reason.  For that reason, I'm voting to leave open.  See also [A Close Vote Is Not a Super Downvote](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) like so:

```
a = [4,1,3]
s = a.map { |count| '*' * count }
#=> ["****", "*", "***"]
```

Comment: It can also be written as `a.map(&?*.method(:*))` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby)

Comment: @MladenJablanović : Yes, it can be. However, it will look a bit complicated to someone who is new to Ruby. As it will require explanation of `?*` which will be char string and then calling multiplication method within `map` which would be applied on the element/value on a particular iteration. So, keeping it simple. Thank you for the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with array contents being replaced, then, following will do it:

```
a.fill {|i|  "*" * a[i]}
#=> ["****", "*", "***"]
```