# How to use &: in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, filter

I have the following construct (simplified):

```
puts ['a!', 'b!', 'c?'].select { |f| f if f.end_with?('!') }
```

It prints

```
a!
b!
```

I want to use an ampersand to make it even shorter:

```
puts ['a!', 'b!', 'c?'].select(&:end_with?('!'))
```

But I get an error:

```
..., 'c?'].select(&:end_with?('!'))
                                 _
x.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `['a!', 'b!', 'c?'].grep(/!\z/)` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the code a *little*, as:

```
puts ['a!', 'b!', 'c?'].select { |f| f.end_with?('!') }
```

You don't need the block to return the element; you just need it to return a "truthy" value.

However, as you have discovered, `&:end_with?('!')` is *not valid ruby syntax*.

There are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23695653/1954610) you could try to implement something clever like that, but in general I'd advise sticking to the syntax above.